# Javascript regex to find two characters between two delimitators

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

**EDITED**

I need to find two characters between '['  ']' and '/'  '/' using Javascript.

I am using this regex:

```
  ([^.][/[string]]|\/string\/)|(\[(string))|(\/(string))| ((string)\])|((string)\/)
```

that gets two charactes but gets too one character.

The question is, how can I do to get just two characters?

Also I want to get exactly the two characters inside the string, I mean not just only the exact match.

Eg.

User input: dz
It must to find just exact matches that contains "dz", e.g. --> "dzone"  but not "dazone". Currently I am getting matches with both strings, "dzone" and "dazone".

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/FEs6ib/1

Comment: Please, edit your question adding examples, input cases and desired ouput

Comment: What is `[^.][/[a]]` supposed to match? Also, what is the purpose of matching `a`? To remove/replace/split?

Comment: If you want to replace, `text.replace(/\/[^\/]*\/|\[[^\][]*]/g, (m) => m.replace(/a/g, ''))` will probably a more comprehensible solution. (Or, with `/\/[^\/\][]*\/|\[[^\/\][]*]/g`). Or, maybe you just want `/\/a\/|\[a]/g`?

Comment: Edited. I need to find two characters joined within a string using regex, but I don't know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 3):

You could optionally repeat any char except the delimiters between the delimiters them selves, and capture in a group what you want to keep.

If you want multiple matches for `/dzone/dzone/` you could assert the last delimiter to the right instead of matching it.

The matches are in group 1 or group 2 where you can check for if they exist.

```
\/[^\/]*(dz)[^\/]*(?=\/)|\[[^\][]*(dz)[^\][]*(?=])
```

The pattern matches:

- `\/` Match `/`
- `[^\/]*(dz)[^\/]*` Capture dz in **group 1** between optional chars other than `/`
- `(?=\/)` Positive lookahead, assert `/` to the right
- `|` Or
- `\[` Match `[`
- `[^\][]*(dz)[^\][]*` Capture dz in **group 2** between optional chars other than `[` and `]`
  -`(?=])` Positive lookahead, assert `]` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1x6aeA/1)

This will match 1 occurrence of dz in the word. If you want to match the whole word, the capture group can be broadened to before and after the negated character class like:

```
\/([^\/]*dz[^\/]*)(?=\/)|\[([^\][]*dz[^\][]*)(?=])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hDZogx/1)

```js
const regex = /\/[^\/]*(dz)[^\/]*(?=\/)|\[[^\][]*(dz)[^\][]*(?=])/g;
[
  "[dzone]",
  "/dzone/",
  "/dzone/dzone/",
  "/testdztest/",
  "[dazone]",
  "/dazone/",
  "dzone",
  "dazone"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(
    `${s} --> ${Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[2] ? m[2] : m[1])}`
  )
);
```

If supported, you might also match all occurrences of `dz` between the delimiters using lookarounds with an infinite quantifier:

```
(?<=\/[^\/]*)dz(?=[^\/]*\/)|(?<=\[[^\][]*)dz(?=[^\][]*])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Hyo1g/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<=\/[^\/]*)dz(?=[^\/]*\/)|(?<=\[[^\][]*)dz(?=[^\][]*])/g;
[
  "[adzadzone]",
  "[dzone]",
  "/dzone/",
  "/dzone/dzone/",
  "/testdztest/",
  "[dazone]",
  "/dazone/",
  "dzone",
  "dazone"
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(`${s} --> ${s.match(regex)}`);
  }
});
```